# Problema con la posición de un botón

Tags: html, css

Quiero saber que tengo que hacer para que el botón del media query se poscicione en la parte derecha de el nav.

```css
/*CODIGO CSS:*/


@media (max-width: 768px) {

/*Acá abajo se encuentra el botón*/

.nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Acá arriba se encuentra el botón*/
  

/*CODIGO HTML:*/
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
          <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Abrir Menú">
            
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            
          </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de posicionar un elemento.
Voy agregar tres ejemplos: `float`, `position` y con Flex box (`margin`).

Este ejemplo es simplemente con `float: right`:

```css
/*CODIGO CSS:*/


@media (max-width: 768px) {

/*Acá abajo se encuentra el botón*/

.nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right
}

/*Acá arriba se encuentra el botón*/
  

/*CODIGO HTML:*/
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
          <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Abrir Menú">
            
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            
          </button>
```

Ahora un ejemplo con `position`. La posición debe ser absoluto, luego la hubicación `right: 0`. Si el botón es de posición absoluto, el contenedor `button-container` debe ser de posición `relative`:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {

#button-container {
  position: relative;
  
  /* Para el demo */
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,128,0, 0.5)
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
  <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Abrir Menú"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>Botón</button>
</div>
```

Este último y más usado es con el uso de Flex box.

El contenedor padre: `button-container` debe tener `display: flex`, y así poder acomodar el contenido a gusto: por ejemplo con `margin: auto` juntamente con `margin-right`.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {

#button-container {
  display: flex;
  
  /* Para el demo */
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,128,0, 0.5)
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
  <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Abrir Menú"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>Botón</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Si te fue útil y correcto mi respuesta, no olvides marcar como aceptada con el ✓. Así será de ayuda para otros que tienes la misma pregunta

Comment: Creo que margin no tiene nada que ver con flexbox. Lo que si tiene relación con posicionar y flexbox son [`justify-content` y `align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#alignment_justification_and_distribution_of_free_space_between_items). De hecho, `margin` establece la distancia con otros elementos y `padding` la distancia del borde a los elementos en su interior.

Comment: Si, tenés razón Mateo. Pero que pasa si hay otros elementos que no necesita posicionar a la derecha? A eso yo iba en concreto